# How to set datatype validation in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have Firebase data structure like this:

[image]

As you can see in the image, the value of `OT1`, `OT1_B`, etc. is Integer. Now, I want such a validation that no one can save value of other data-type for this key.

How can set I rule for this kind of restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a rule available to validate your data in FireBase RealTime Database. Use `.validate` rule to check if your data is a string or other type and you can also use regular expression to check the matches.
Refer the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data) to check how to Validate Data under section
 **Validating Data**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking user input for that fields then simply adding ,

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

will do a work for you